# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mongo' not found

Tags: php, mongodb

I've been trying to install the MongoDB extension for PHP for a while now with no luck. I followed the standard steps:

- Installed the driver via Pecl
- Added it to my PHP.ini file (both CLI and Apache2)
- Restarted Apache2

Yet, my code believes it does not exist:

```php
$conn = new Mongo($_ENV["DB"]);
$db = $conn->test;
```

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Mongo' not found in /var/www/ag/API/index.php:22\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/ag/API/index.php on line 22
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I am using PHP 7.3 and Apache 2.4.38 on Debian

I saw a question like this for Windows, but it was of no help to me.

Comment: I believe you need to use ``$conn = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager($_ENV["DB"]);``. Also they recommend installing the library as well. https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!